# Prediction interval of Y given AR model for log(Y)

Tags: arima, data-transformation, prediction, lognormal-distribution, prediction-interval

I have been given an AR model with seasonal variation. 
\begin{equation}
(1-\theta_1B)(1-\theta_2B^8)(log(Y_t)-\mu)=\epsilon_t
\end{equation}
Setting $X_t=log(Y_t)-\mu$ one gets the following

\begin{equation}X_t=\epsilon_t+\theta_1X_{t-1}+\theta_2X_{t-8}-\theta_1\theta_2X_{t-9}.
\end{equation}

We are given $\theta_1$, $\theta_2$ and the last 16 observations of $log(Y_t)$. $\epsilon_t$ is white noise and $\epsilon_t\sim N(0,\sigma_{\epsilon}^2)$.

The one and two step predictions thus become (where the know observations are called $\textbf{X}_t$).
\begin{align}
E[X_{t+1}|\textbf{X}_t]&=E[\epsilon_{t+1}|\textbf{X}_t]+\theta_1E[X_{t}|\textbf{X}_t]+\theta_2E[X_{t-7}|\textbf{X}_t]-\theta_1\theta_2E[X_{t-8}|\textbf{X}_t]\\&=\theta_1X_{t}+\theta_2X_{t-7}-\theta_1\theta_2X_{t-8}=\hat{X_{t+1}}\\
E[X_{t+2}|\textbf{X}_t]&=E[\epsilon_{t+2}|\textbf{X}_t]+\theta_1E[X_{t+1}|\textbf{X}_t]+\theta_2E[X_{t-6}|\textbf{X}_t]-\theta_1\theta_2E[X_{t-7}|\textbf{X}_t]\\&=\theta_1E[X_{t+1}|\textbf{X}_t]+\theta_2X_{t-6}-\theta_1\theta_2X_{t-7}=\hat{X_{t+2}}
\end{align}

And the variance of the prediction errors become

\begin{align}
V[X_{t+1}-\hat{X_{t+1}}]&=V[\epsilon_{t+1}+\theta_1X_{t}+\theta_2X_{t-7}-(\theta_1\theta_2X_{t-8}-\theta_1X_{t}+\theta_2X_{t-7}-\theta_1\theta_2X_{t-8})]\\
&=\sigma_\epsilon^2\\
V[X_{t+2}-\hat{X_{t+2}}]&=V[\epsilon_{t+2}+\theta_1X_{t+1}+\theta_2X_{t-6}-\theta_1\theta_2X_{t-7}-(\theta_1E[X_{t+1}|\textbf{X}_t]+\theta_2X_{t-6}-\theta_1\theta_2X_{t-7})]\\
&=V[\epsilon_{t+1}+\theta_1(X_{t+1}-\hat{X_{t+1}})]=(1+\theta_1^2)\sigma_\epsilon^2
\end{align}

My issue is now that I need the 95% prediction interval.
What I thought (and my question is whether this is correct) I could was the following where $\hat{log(Y_{t+1})}=\hat{X_{t+1}}+\mu$, $\hat{log(Y_{t+2})}=\hat{X_{t+2}}+\mu$, $V[log(Y_{t+1})-\hat{log(Y_{t+1})}]=\sigma_\epsilon^2$ and $V[log(Y_{t+2})-\hat{log(Y_{t+2})}]=(1+\theta_1^2)\sigma_\epsilon^2$. As $log(Y_t)$ can be written as an MA process then $log(Y_t)$ follows a normal distribution and thus $Y_t$ follows a log-normal distribution. Thus using expressions from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution gives that the 95% ($\alpha=0.05$) prediction interval for $Y_{t+k}$ becomes
\begin{align}
&[lnN_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}(m_k,v_k),\ lnN_{\frac{1-\alpha}{2}}(\text{exp}(m_k,v_k)]\\
m_k&=\text{exp}(\hat{log(Y_{t+k})}+\frac{V[log(Y_{t+k})-\hat{log(Y_{t+k})}]^2}{2}\\
v_k&=(\text{exp}(V[log(Y_{t+k})-\hat{log(Y_{t+k})}])-1)\text{exp}(2\hat{log(Y_{t+k})}+V[log(Y_{t+k})-\hat{log(Y_{t+k})}]^2)
\end{align}
Where $lnN_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}(m_k,v_k)$ is the $\frac{\alpha}{2}$ quantile of a log-normal distribution with mean and variance respectively $m_k$ and $v_k$.

Comment: An idea for you: post the question as a question and your candidate answer as an answer to your own question. This way people can respond to the question and/or to the answer by voting, commenting, etc.